# JavaScriptでrequireするとError: Cannot find module

Tags: javascript, browserify

BitcoinトランザクションのブロードキャストができるWebサイトをつくりたく、[このサイト](http://noumenon-th.net/webstrategy/2015/04/30/bitcoin/)のコードを一部改変し、ブラウザで実行したところ以下のエラーが出ました。

```
Error: Cannot find module 'bitcore-explorers'
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

BitCoreというJavaScriptライブラリの[ドキュメント](https://bitcore.io/guides/browser)を参考にbitcore-libとbitcore-explorersを`bower install`したのですが、モジュールが見つからないのは何が原因なのでしょうか。

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ja">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<script src="bower_components/bitcore-lib/bitcore-lib.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/bitcore-explorers/bitcore-explorers.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

  <script type="text/javascript">

  var bitcore = require('bitcore-lib');
  var explorers = require('bitcore-explorers');
  var insight = new explorers.Insight();

  var a_address = "";//Aアドレス
  var privateKey ="";//Aのプライベートキー

  getUTXO(a_address, function(utxos){

        utxos.forEach(function(utxo){console.log(utxo.toJSON());});

        //トランザクション生成
        var transaction = new bitcore.Transaction().fee(10000)
          .from(utxos)
          .addData('')
          .change('')      // Sets up a change address where the rest of the funds will go
          .sign(privateKey)

        console.log("transaction",transaction.toJSON());

        broadcast(transaction, function(id){
          console.log(id);
  　　});

  });

  function getUTXO(address, done)
  {
    //utxosの取得
    insight.getUnspentUtxos(address, function(err, utxos) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
      done(utxos);
    });
  }

  function broadcast(tx, done)
  {
    //ブロードキャスト
    insight.broadcast(tx, function(err, id) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
       done(id);
    });
  }

  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `bitcore-explorers`は以下[リンク](https://github.com/bitpay/bitcore-explorers)からinstallするものですが、`bitcore-lib`にはありませんが、それは大丈夫ですか？

Answer (score 1):

自己回答です。
bitcore-explorersを[GitHub](https://github.com/bitpay/bitcore-explorers)からinstallしたところ、問題なくrequireできました。